# Understanding how $n$ choose $k$ work.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Let's say that we have $4$ people and $2$ chairs, how many ways we can arrange these people into these chairs?

I know that the answer is just $${4\choose 2} = \frac{4!}{(4-2)!\cdot2!}=\frac{24}{4}=6$$

but I don't quite understand the reason why this is the case, we have $2$ chairs and $4$ people so in the first chair you have $4$ possibilities and in the second you have $3$ ones, thus the answer should be $4\cdot 3=12$ but this isn't the right answer, where is the mistake?

Comment: Well, that depends on whether the chairs are considered the same. You might thing person A in the left chair and B in the right chair is  is “different” from seating B in the left chair and A in the right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very common issue in combinatorics: Identifying what you *actually* care about. Do you only care about which two people get to sit? Then $6$ is the answer. Do you care about which person sits in which chair? Then $12$ is the answer.

If you only care about which people two get to sit, then focusing on the people rather than the chairs might be a good idea. Choose two of the four people to get $\binom 42$.

If you care about which person sits where, then focusing on the chairs might be a good idea. The first chair has $4$ options, the second chair then has $3$ options, for a total of $12$ options.

The connection is this: in the second approach above, the two people that are ultimately chosen can be chosen in $2$ ways. Note that $\binom42=\frac{4!}{2!\cdot2!}=\frac{4\cdot3}{2}$. See the $4\cdot3$ in the numerator, and recognize that as the answer from the second approach, and recognize the denominator from the $2$ ways the two people can be chosen.

Comment: Ah, yes, it does seem an unusual way to approach the question - it is unusual to leave people standing in this kind of problem.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Indeed. Usually this kind of problem has enough chairs for everyone, often with a few to spare. It's late and I didn't read the statement properly.

Answer (score 2):

The error lies in the fact that your method counts each pair of persons twice. If we are talking about Alice, Bob, Claire, and David, your approach counts the case in which Alice got the first chair and Bob got the second one as distinct from the case in which Bob got the first chair and Alice got the second one. But it is the *same* situation: the situation in which those two who get chairs are Alice and Bob.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing *combinations* ($C^n_k$ or $\binom nk$) with *permutations* ($P^n_k$).

We have:

$$C^n_k=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$
which denotes the number of combinations; arrangements where order doesn't matter, and:
$$P^n_k=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$$
which denotes permutations; arrangements where order does matter.

Comment: +1. It is good that the terms combination and permutation are mentioned so that the OP can read and find out more.

Comment: Is the OP confused? As I read it, the stated problem is ambiguous but, to my mind, leans toward a permutations interpretation (because of the phrase "arrange into"). I personally avoid using the word "arrangement" when posing problems about selection processes.